# When can a rational function be represented by a Taylor series?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am trying to prove that

$$
\int_C \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)} dz = 0
$$

If polynomial order of $Q$ is 2 or more than that of $P$, using the theorem stating that if a function has a finite number of singular points all interior to a contour $C$, then

$$
\int_C f(z) dz = 2\pi i\text{Res}\bigg[\frac{1}{z^2} f(\frac{1}{z})\bigg]
$$

I received the hint that, under the conditions described above, the rational function in the integrand can be written as a McLauran Series with no negative powers of z. This would imply that the residue is zero...

My problem is, I can't seem to wrap my head around how the rational function given to me can be written into the form of a power series with only positive exponents...

So, as the title says, When can a rational function be represented as a power series? I'm not looking for a full proof, but a few details would be nice, just so I feel more comfortable running with the hint.

Comment: Not really. The idea of the residue at infinity is that  $$\int_{|z|=R} f(z) dz = -\int_{|s|=1/R} f(1/s) d(1/s) =  \int_{|s|=1/R} \frac{f(1/s)}{s^2} ds$$ 

For $f$ a rational function, let $r = |\rho|$ the largest pole then the integral doesn't depend on $R> r$. 

Since $\frac{f(1/s)}{s^2} = \sum_{n=-N}^{-1} c_n s^{n}+ h(s)$ with $h$ a polynomial then you can integrate each term and obtain the result as $2i\pi c_{-1}$.

Comment: What is $N$ ? When is it $0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that whenever you center the expansion at a point where the function is analytic, it can be represented as a Taylor series. In this specific case, we will see that the function in question is analytic at $z=0$ and therefore has a Maclaurin expansion.

To see why we can write $\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{P(\frac{1}{z})}{Q(\frac{1}{z})}$ as a Taylor series centered at $z=0$, consider distributing the $\frac{1}{z^2}$ onto the rational function as shown below:

$$
g(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{P(\frac{1}{z})}{Q(\frac{1}{z})} = \frac{a_0 + a_1\frac{1}{z} + \dots + a_n\frac{1}{z^n}}{b_0z^2 + b_1z + b_2 + \dots+b_m\frac{1}{z^{m-2}}} \times \frac{z^{m-2}}{z^{m-2}} = \frac{a_0z^{m-2} + a_1z^{m-3} + \dots + a_nz^{m-n-2}}{b_0z^m + b_1z^{m-1} + \dots+b_m}
$$

Now, take note of the far right hand side of the above equation and consider what happens when $z=0$. Because we know $b_m$ is non zero, the denominator is non-zero at $z=0$. This means that $g(z)$ is analytic at $z=0$

We know then that if a function is analytic within some neighborhood of $z=0$ that it can be written as a Maclaurin power series:

$$
g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n z^n 
$$

Because there are no negative powers of $z$ in this expansion, its residue is zero at $z=0$.

Using the above information and the fact that $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ is analytic except for a finite number $n$ of singular points (the zeros of $Q$) contained in a large enough contour $C$, then:

$$ 
\int_C f(z)dz = 2\pi i \sum_{j=1}^n\underset{z = z_j}{\text{Res}}[f(x)] = 2\pi i { \underset{z = 0}{\text{Res}}\bigg[\frac{1}{z^2}f\bigg(\frac{1}{z}\bigg)\bigg]} = 0
$$